# What determines speed of Record Update on Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

This is more of a general curiosity question than a problem, but my Record update in a Flow is working slowly (takes a few refreshes to see the change).

I'm used to using Apex and seeing the change almost instantly.  Is there any way to speed this up?

Details:

- Using Professional Edition
- Flow is in a Lightning component wrapper on Case Page
- Flow has 2 lookup components (looks up case, then the second one looks up the related record that is to be updated)
- Finally it is updating the record (at this time it is only updated a checkbox value on 1 field on 1 record

[image]

Comment: It's more likely a data caching issue. When the flow completes, the data is updated.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks, I've got some reading to do in the developer blog about this